# Getting an R Notebook to work in Jetbrains Dataspell

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, data-science, dataspell

So I am just starting a data science/stats class and I am trying to setup a R notebook within Dataspell I am able to create a Jupyter notbook but it only wants a python interpreter and I can't seem to change the interpreter to R

[image: dataspell]

[image: python]

[image]

I only allows me to set a python interpreter. I am able to run R files just fine but I am trying to do it in a notebook. (Whether that be Jupyter or some other notebook I couldn't care less)

I would like to stick to Jetbrains IDE's either Dataspell or Pycharm. I tried our Datalore and got an R notebook working but its really slow for me.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there's an (currently - as of May 2022) undocumented feature in Dataspell 2022.1 which they have been developing which supports R kernels in Dataspell as an IDE.

If you have an Conda environment which has R and the `irkernel` installed and configured (for instance, if you set up your Anaconda environment to run Jupyter notebooks with the R kernel), you can open existing R notebooks in Dataspell and run them just like Python notebooks.  The only thing you can't do is create *new* ones, sadly.

Basically, just use Anaconda or Miniconda to create an environment which can run Jupyter notebooks with the `irkernel`, create your notebooks in Jupyter, then point your Dataspell directory at it and it should work.

They do mention that it's a developing feature - so if you encounter bugs, you can flag them in the Dataspell issue tracker.  I tried it and it worked pretty well so far.

You can see an example of my R kernel running in Dataspell here:
[image: Example]

Comment: I tried what you suggest here, thanks. However, when I try to open the notebook I created i Jupyter Lab in Data Spell, nothing happens. I get all the R windows in Data Spell, such as console and plots, but the notebook is not opened. I work with Data Spell 2022.2
Update: It works now, after I shut down anaconda and the running jupyterlab and restarted Data Spell. 
A good workaround until Data Spell will let us create R notebooks.

Comment: Here's how I was able to make it work: after reading above and installing irkernel in Anaconda, I was able to create a notebook in Data Spell, click the "Open in Browser" link, then in Jupyter change the kernel to R and save the notebook, next reopen the notebook in Data Spell and the option to change the interpreter to R in the top drop down was available.  Data Spell 2022.1.4 and R 4.2.1.

Comment: Did you created a conda environment in DataSpell in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

DataSpell can be a little difficult to navigate. In any case, File>New... pops up a menu:

[image: New Popup Menu]

Pick "RMarkdown File", which your purposes will work the same as a notebook. RStudio has both markdown and notebook options, but they still have an Rmd extension.

You should also see a R Console button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I actually have exactly the same issue as this, but the answer below will not suit my needs.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi John, I can get your solution to work in Pycharm, but in DataSpell, I need help getting the conda environment to be listed as an alternative interpreter. I can create conda environment in DataSpell, which can be confirmed in anaconda3\envs. but Dataspell does not list it in the Python Interpreter UI. Do you have any suggestions?